# Outlook iOS Unable to Signin after using for some time

Tags: ios, outlook, adal

I am unable sign in after using application for some time. If we reset the device and retry to signin , It works without any issue. What could be the problem ?

Using below Pods: -

pod 'Office365'
pod 'ADALiOS', '~> 1.2.2'

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: Please update your question to include the error message, ADAL code snippets, scenario/configs.

Comment: Finally i was able to find the problem.  It seems to be already there was one existing user session it was stoping to login.   Below changes i have done to solve problem
1. Modified promptBehavior: AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS  to promptBehavior: AD_PROMPT_AUTO , after this change without resetting the device i am able to login.
2. Also we had a functionality to do logout. In that we were not clearing the session properly. then added session clear code

id<ADTokenCacheStoring> cache = [ADAuthenticationSettingssharedInstance].defaultTokenCacheStore;
    [cache removeAllWithError:nil];